# Force browser download in Servlet- Spring

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, download

I am new to Spring MVC and I had a doubt about accessing the `HttpServletResponse` object in a servlet.

Basically my code is something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/part of requesturl")
@ResponseBody String methodName(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    //All the computations which build up a JSon

    return json;
}
```

Right now this `json` file is being displayed on the browser as a response. I need to force it to be downloaded to the disk of the user irrespective of the browser. By looking at the other posts, I figured I should do someting like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
```

How do I get the response object here? Also, if someone could shed some more light on forcing download onto the browser that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> How do I get the response object here ?

Very intuitive:

```
@ResponseBody String methodName(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response
) {
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
        //...
}
```

> Also, if someone could shed some more light on forcing download onto the browser that would be great.

See:

- [How to force browser to download file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231)
- [Utility of HTTP header "Content-Type: application/force-download" for mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615797)