# Simulate start writing servlet response

Tags: java, servlets, response, apache-poi, outputstream

We have a servlet that prints a server side generated Excel file to the response output stream. The Excel file is generated by a single method which returns the complete file in a POI Workbook object.

Our problem is that the method which generates the file lasts almost 30 seconds to execute. The clients keeps waiting for response all this time until we start writing the file to the response.

Is there any way to write "something" in the response to make the client navigator fire the download dialog?

Something like...

```
response.getOutputStream().write(null);
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

*(Writing null in an outputStream throws a NullPointerException)*

This way the download would seem to have been started although the file would be yet getting generated.

Comment: Do you mean "Please wait loading page.." ?

Comment: You could use a polling method but this introduces a more complicated asynchronous design. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Here have some info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231/how-to-force-browser-to-download-file

Comment: Could you setup a thread that periodically writes a zero byte array and flushes, until the workbook generation is complete and that can be streamed?