# Opening PDF files in the browser vulnerability

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, pdf, download

We have a Java based web application deployed on WebLogic. We provide direct links to some PDF files, which the users can download/ open in their browser. Our security team is claiming that to allow opening PDF files in the browser is a security risk. So they want to force the users to download the PDF files first rather than opening them in the browser window.

1. Is this really a security risk?
2. If the PFD is a trogen/ vulnerable, how come downloading the file first and opening it could solve the problem?
3. Is their a way to programmatically prevent the user from opening the PDF files in the browser window and to force downloading the PDF files first?

Comment: Have you tried setting response content type as : response.setContentType("application/force-download"); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231/how-to-force-browser-to-download-file

Comment: Thanx for the comment @HRgiger. The pdf files in the system are added by a CMS. This CMS places direct links to PDF. i.e. host:7001/contextroot/files/fileName.pdf. (Files are not written by an output stream.) So how can I set the content type. Writing a Servlet Filter would be a solution?

Comment: Well I would give a shot:)

Comment: I'd expect downloading a PDF to be much more a security risk than opening it in the browser.

Comment: 2> it doesn't prevent anything. An Adobe Reader vulnerability can be exploited in the browser or out.

Comment: Did you ask Q.2 to your security team?

Answer (score 1):

To force the browser to give download option to the PDF :

response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the user to save a PDF file first and then open it is actually likely to be more risky than allowing it to be opened in the browser.

It's not better:

- Any vulnerabilities in your PDF reader (probably Adobe Reader) will be triggered whether it is opened now or later.
- Any decent virus scanner will be able to scan a PDF before it is opened, no matter if the pdf was downloaded to a temporary internet files folder, or some other user selected folder (e.g. downloads).  (But if these are your PDF files, viruses probably aren't much of a concern.)

But it might be worse:

- If the client is Firefox, then allowing the pdf to be opened directly will lead to PDF.js being used, which is likely to be [more secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/31549/18452) than Adobe Reader. In bypassing this client, you're exposing your users to greater risk.
- You are conditioning users to download and open files from the internet. A minor point, but the more you can avoid this the better.