# How to get ContentType of a blob?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, blob

I have my website which allows users to upload pdf , word or images to database. It is stored as blob. Now while viewing the files i have used the following code

display_file.jsp

```
 Blob  b = rs.getBlob(img);
 InputStream is = b.getBinaryStream();
 OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte buf[] = new byte[(int) b.length()];
                    is.read(buf);
                    os.write(buf);
                    os.close();
```

and show_files.jsp

```
<a href="PhotoDisplay.jsp?img=image4&id=<%=contractNo%>" >Image 4 </a>
```

Whenever i click on this link if it is image it is shown on the webbrowser.
However if it is pdf a download prompt is open in the browser and i have to download it.

Now i want to show the pdf on the webbrowser too. How can i do that  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set valid http headers, like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

Also read this discussion, they have the opposite problem: [How to force browser to download file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231/how-to-force-browser-to-download-file)

Comment: First step for me would be to know what is the contentType of data i am dealing with it is after that i have to use pdf or word or doc