# How can I do a download button in html

Tags: html, css

I want to make a download button, I have this line of code but it opens the txt file in Google:

```
      <a href="data/info.txt" download="data/info.txt">Download
      <button class="btn" style:height: 200px; width: 100px; download><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
      </a>
```

Comment: Having a link around a button is... very strange.  Which one is the user clicking?  Why not just use the link and style it to look like a button?  Seems like it'd be easier to control its behavior that way.

Comment: It is invalid HTML to have a `button` within an `a`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force browser to download file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231/how-to-force-browser-to-download-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192917/force-download-through-js-or-query

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know `download` should be a filename, not a path. Does changing `download` to `download="info.txt"` work?

Answer (score -2):

Which browser do you use?
When I click on this button

```
<a href="info.txt" download="data/info.txt">
  <button class="btn" style:height: 200px; width: 100px; download>
    Download
  </button>
</a>
```

Chrome starts downloading the file.
I've tried it on [this](https://blank.mfest.dev/) page